# How to create 'Partial' Search?

Tags: commerce, search

I'm using Drupal commerce and I was wondering if there is a way to do partial search? Current the search engine is only searching the exact word. E.g. Candy or Battery I'm looking to search with only term 'Can' or 'Bat'. Please advise.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to employ some sort of stemming algorithm for that.

The [Porter-Stemmer](https://www.drupal.org/project/porterstemmer) module is a possible choice:

> This module implements the Porter stemming algorithm to improve English-language searching with the Drupal built-in Search module.

Answer (score 0):

1.On yoursite/admin/config/search/search_api/ choose "*edit*" your server   type (not index type)configuration.

2.At the bottom of the page set the "*Search on parts of the word*"checkbox checked.

Comment: Any idea what else one needs to do to make this work with 8? Even after making this setting and reindexing the content, it does not work.